# localStorage not persisting on Ionic (Cordova) app rebuild with Java 8

Tags: java, android, cordova, ionic-framework

I've been developing my app for 10 months and in all that time I've been using localStorage to persist user data. I know there are better options but it has served my purpose fine up to now.

I'm just developing for Android and I would write my code and then install onto my phone with `ionic run android --device`

The changes would be installed and my user data would still be there.

However, just today I needed to upgrade to use Java 8 rather than 7 in order to support the new Google Play Services (I think that's what required it).

Now whenever I rebuild and reinstall the app with `ionic run android --device` all of my localStorage data is wiped and the app installs as if totally new.

Is this to be expected?
Is there something I can change to make it work like it did before?

Many thanks for any responses.

Potentially useful information
$ ionic -version
2.0.0

$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_101"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)

$ cordova -version
5.4.0

OS
Windows 10

Android version (on phone)
6.0.1 - security patch 5 October 2016.
(Just updated today so potentially also a cause of the change)

Answer (score 1):

Are you using sqlite as the storage driver?

In your app.module.ts

```
IonicStorageModule.forRoot({
  name: '__yourapp-localstorage',
     driverOrder: ['sqlite','indexeddb', 'websql']
}),
```